# Zabbix Not Triggering Events and Not Sending Notification Emails

Tags: email, zabbix, amazon-ses

I am new to Zabbix administration. Running it to monitor server resources on a linux machine. Setting up Email notifications against trigger's expression `if System RAM goes below 40GB`. Using Amazon SES for SMTP settings as mentioned in attached **figure#1**. In **figure#2** it shows the action settings supposed to send email to `abc@xyz.com`.

1. Zabbix is not triggering the events at first place.
2. Zabbix is not sending emails using amazon SES

Please help me in figuring out what the issue and enable zabbix to send email properly.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with that sendEmail script. Put the $1, $2 and $3 variable in double quotes so it looks like this:

```
export zabbixemailto="$1"
export zabbixsubject="$2"
export zabbixbody="$3"
```

Without double quotes even whitespaces will give you problems, if they happen to be in subject and/or body of the message.

Answer (score 0):

It looks OK. try to:

1.) enable debug zabbix server option

```
DebugLevel=4
```

and check logs, maybe zabbix server is not able to find or execute your script (btw: has zabbix user sudo permission?)

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/appendix/config/zabbix_server

2.) log execution of you script, e.g.

```
date >> /tmp/execution.log
```

Maybe you script is executed correctly, but emails are not delivered - so problem is not zabbix

3.) remove some conditions from action

Are you sure with all conditions? Maybe some of them are too strict. You can try:

http://blog.zabbix.com/why-on-earth-was-i-not-notified/2027/